# Google Cloud Monitoring Ruby client permission issue

Tags: metrics, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am following the Ruby code sample to add a custom metrics to stackdriver, however, I keep getting the permission denied error.

```
client = Google::Cloud::Monitoring::Metric.new
project_name = Google::Cloud::Monitoring::V3::MetricServiceClient.project_path project_id

descriptor = Google::Api::MetricDescriptor.new(
  type:        "custom.googleapis.com/my_metric#{random_suffix}",
  metric_kind: Google::Api::MetricDescriptor::MetricKind::GAUGE,
  value_type:  Google::Api::MetricDescriptor::ValueType::DOUBLE,
  description: "This is a simple example of a custom metric."
)

result = client.create_metric_descriptor project_name, descriptor
```

the error I got is "**Google::Gax::PermissionDeniedError (GaxError RPC failed, caused by 7:Permission monitoring.metricDescriptors.create denied (or the resource may not exist).)**"

The environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is set, and it works fine for the Google Cloud Storage code below

```
storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new project: project_id

# Make an authenticated API request
storage.buckets.each do |bucket|
  puts bucket.name
end
```

At this point, I don't know what is the problem.  Do I need to set up a different credential for Cloud Monitoring?

Comment: Where is your code running? If it's on a Compute Engine instance, does it have the proper `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring` scope? Does your service account have the proper permissions?

Comment: that was the issue. thanks!